# Specifying multiple environments in Geb

Tags: geb

I am working on a project where three different deployment environments are in use. The difference between them is just different URLs. So my question is: "Is it possible to do something like this:"

```java
browsers {
  chrome {
    driver = {
      new ChromeDriver()
    }
  }
  firefox {
    driver = {
    new FirefoxDriver();
    }
  }
} 

environments {
  development {
    baseUrl = "https://baseUrl.dev"
  }
  staging {
    baseUrl = "https://baseUrl.stage"
  }
  production {
    baseUrl = "https://baseUrl.prod"
  }
}
```

In order to be able to run my tests like this: `gradle test -Dgeb.env="development" -Dgeb.browser="chrome"` instead of doing like this:

```java
environments {
  developmentChrome {
    driver = {
      new ChromeDriver();
    }
    baseUrl = "https://baseUrl.dev"
  }
  stagingChrome {
    driver = {
      new ChromeDriver();
    }
    baseUrl = "https://baseUrl.stage"
  }
  productionChrome {
    driver = {
      new ChromeDriver();
    }
    baseUrl = "https://baseUrl.prod"
  }

  developmentFirefox {
    driver = {
      new FirefoxDriver();
    }
    baseUrl = "https://baseUrl.dev"
  }
  stagingFirefox {
    driver = {
      new FirefoxDriver();
    }
    baseUrl = "https://baseUrl.stage"
  }
  productionFirefox {
    driver = {
      new FirefoxDriver();
    }
    baseUrl = "https://baseUrl.prod"
  }
}
```

and running them like this: `gradle test -Dgeb.env="productionFirefox"`

Answer (score 2):

I did the following, then you can run for example:

```
./gradlew dev-chromeTest
```

I expect having the build.gradle from geb example project:
https://github.com/geb/geb-example-gradle/blob/master/build.gradle

then I add an array with the base urls beneath the drivers array:

```
drivers = ["chrome", "firefox"]
baseUrls = [
    [name: "dev", url: "http://dev-url.com/"],
    [name: "beta", url: "http://beta-url.com/"],
]
```

I modified the task section the following:

```
baseUrls.each { entry ->
    drivers.each { driver ->
        task "${entry.name}-${driver}Test"(type: Test) {
            group JavaBasePlugin.VERIFICATION_GROUP

            outputs.upToDateWhen { false }  // Always run tests

            systemProperty "geb.build.reportsDir", reporting.file("geb/$name")
            systemProperty "geb.env", driver
            systemProperty "geb.build.baseUrl", entry.url
        }
    }
}
```

and the test section this way:

```
test {
    dependsOn drivers.collect { baseUrls.each{ entry -> tasks["${entry.name}-${it}Test"]} }
    enabled = false
}
```

In the end you can then run your tests like:

```
./gradlew dev-chromeTest
```

or

```
./gradlew beta-chromeTest
```

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to stick to the Geb convention and use `geb.env` to determine which type of browser driver to instantiate. According to the [documentation](http://www.gebish.org/manual/current/#driver-caching-configuration) (scroll to paragraph 7.2.4) you can use system property `geb.build.baseUrl` to directly configure the base URL. You can easily do that from your Maven or Gradle script instead of putting that logic into `GebConfig`. If you insist, you can still set that or any other home-brew property to a symbolic value and resolve it in `GebConfig` with a little bit of manual coding. Remember, you can use any type of Groovy code there, such as Groovy's powerful [switch statement](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2009/08/groovy-goodness-switch-statement.html). That way you could also implement your non-intuitive logic of using `geb.env` for deployment environments and something like `geb.browser` for the drivers. But as I said: Following Geb conventions would probably be better for anyone who has to understand or maintain your code later.

Feel free to ask follow-up questions if anything is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're also using Spock.  This is how I deal with multiple environments...

Geb Config:

Use a DriverFactory class to create the driver based on the browser property ( -Dbrowser), if it isn't set default to "chrome".

baseUrl is set based on the given -Dgeb.env value.

```
driver = DriverFactory.createDriver(System.getProperty("browser", "chrome"))

environments {
    dev {
        baseUrl = "https://myDevUrl/"
    }
    qa {
        baseUrl = "https://myQaEnvironmentUrl"
        }
    }
    local {
        baseUrl = "https://mylocalurl/"
    }
}
```

Create annotations in a separate class to annotate tests that are to be run on specific environments:

```
import java.lang.annotation.*

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target([ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD])
@Inherited
@interface dev {}

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target([ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD])
@Inherited
@interface qa {}
```

Add the following to the SpockConfig so correct tests are run:

```
def environments = [dev: dev, qa: qa, local: dev]

def gebEnv = System.getProperty("geb.env")

if (gebEnv) {
    runner {
        include environments[gebEnv]
    }
}
```

Annotate all your test classes like so:

```
@dev @qa
class ExampleSpec extends BaseGebSpec {


    def "A test to be run on dev and qa"() {

        given: "Some stuff"

           //Some code

        when: "Do some stuff"

            //More code

        then: "Stuff happens"

            //Assertion code
    }
}
```

So now you should be able to run specific tests with a specific environment/browser.

Answer (score 0):

@Rushby

I tried your response to make it work, of course am beginner on geb spoke, but assuming having different urls on one environment and having different data sources for each environment like for example
DEV envronment  "https://finandepartment-dev.test.com","https://hrdepartment-dev.test.com"
QA envronment  "https://finandepartment-qa.test.com","https://hrdepartment-qa.test.com"

and the DEV environment have dev database connection, and QA environment to have QA database connection, how would you configure the environment when run tests based on the environment, which I might have to use both the url (finance and HR) on test may be getting data from one url and use it on the other url, like API tests. I really would appreciate your reply(for possible solutions)